# TestFlight 2.0.0 : "MyApp" isn't compatible with this device

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode9

This is latest **TestFlight app** issue when I build my project with new Xcode 9.0.

I don't understand whether it's TestFlight issue or new Xcode has done any changes in the compatibility settings. Because I can still install the previous builds which I have built using Xcode 8.3 on the same device through TestFlight.

Need help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after having done 8 successful builds through TestFlight in iTunes Connect. My 9th build for some reason started to show the "Incompatible Hardware" error inside TestFlight on all of my older test devices.

This ended up not being an issue with TestFlight but with my archive. When I created the archive in XCode I had unintentionally left the device next to the active scheme (upper right corner of XCODE next to the play button) set to a physical device (i.e. my iPhone 6) instead of "Generic iOS Device". Once I changed this back to "Generic iOS Device" and created a new archive, everything started working again on older devices.

[image]